# Добавить префикс к функциям, константам и глобальным переменным

Tags: c, makefile

Пишу библиотеку на C, использую CMake. И для того, чтобы избежать конфликтов с именами в коде, который будет использовать эту библиотеку я использую следующий подход именования:

`<LIBRARY_NAME>_<FUNCTION_NAME>`

Что удлиняет написание функций и, что более важно, ухудшает читабельность.

Есть ли что-то, что позволит добавить нужный префикс автоматически, перед компиляцией? Или, если вообще подход верный (я допускаю, что возможно то, что я хочу - это что-то из разряда того, что люди в здравом уме не делают), как такое правильнее всего было бы самому написать?

Comment: Напишите набор `#define`-ов, для все ваших внешних имен с префиксами, которые вы хотите видеть в сосрсах короткими

Comment: Это что-то есть в С++ и называется пространства имен. @avp только вот от конфликтов имен с другими библиотеками такой подход не защитит. Зато гарантирует много веселых часов разборок происхождения того или иного символа.

Comment: @VTT, не защитит точно также, как и namespace. Конфликт ведь возникнет на уровне линкера. Так что, в любом случае, все зависит от уникальности префикса. Вообще, должен сказать, что сама идея "прятать префикс в сорсах" мне не слишком нравится, но если ТС-у хочется решения, то вот оно.

Comment: @avp namespace как раз защитит.

Comment: @VTT, ну, расскажите каким образом (лучше с распечаткой таблиц символов)

Comment: @avp Ну а что тут рассказывать? Если есть две библиотеки с двумя функциями `foo` и использовать препроцессор, то будет два одинаковых символа `foo`, а если использовать пространства имен, то будет два разных символа, какие-нибудь `@#4lib1@$**foo` и `@#4lib2@$**foo`

Comment: @VTT, в lib1 X::foo(), в lib2 тоже X::foo(). Включаете в f1.cpp lib1, а в f2.cpp lib2 и каким волшебным образом namespace **X из lib1** начинает именоваться не так, как ***X из lib2***?

Comment: @avp С чего вдруг они будут одинаковыми придерживаясь той же схемы `<LIBRARY_NAME>_<FUNCTION_NAME>`? В lib1 будет lib1::foo(), в lib 2 будет `lib2::foo`. Никаких коллизий. А вот есть делать набор дефайнов, для всех внешних имен, то в каком-то месте возможна коллизия с коротким именем из второй библиотеки.

Comment: @VTT, т.е. все же в lib1 namespace не X, а lib1, соответственно и в lib2 так же? Тогда да. И с define так же.

Comment: @avp Нет, с дефайнами также не получится, потому что короткие имена по-прежнему будут вызвать конфликты.

Comment: @VTT, вы о том, что ошибиться с дефайнами легче, чем с namespace? С этим соглашусь, если о чем-то другом, то не понимаю о каких коротких именах идет речь.